# Passar body em requisição GET

Tags: api, mobile, flutter, dart

Bom dia amigos. Como posso passar um **body** na requisição **GET**?

Tenho um API que faz uma busca por CPF em um PDF e me retorna a página em que ele se encontra. No terminal, o comando é o seguinte:

```
http GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/processed/cpf.pdf data="123.456.789-10"
```

Gostaria de consumir essa API com Dart/Flutter, mas não consigo passar o body na requisição. Tentei com o seguinte código:

```
   class PdfSearch{
      
      Future catchPage(String numero) async {
      Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/processed/cpf.pdf");
      http.Request request = http.Request("GET", uri);
      request.body = '{"data": $numero}';
      final response = request.send().asStream().first;
    
  }

}
```

Sem sucesso...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Endpoints GET originalmente não deveriam conter body na requisição, é justamente por isso que o método `http.get()` [não tem](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/get.html) um parâmetro `body`. Pois ele é simplesmente ignorado.

```dart
Future<Response> get(Uri url,{Map<String, String>? headers})
```

Se ele é necessário, isso pode indicar um bad design na criação da API.
No seu caso, seria mais indicado a utilização de [queryParams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/processed/cpf.pdf?cpf=12345678910
```

Ferramentas que fazem cache de APIs por exemplo, se utilizam da url para isso.
Assim, é possível passar os dados na url utilizando o seu próprio código.